# Parsley-rails form not submitting rails 5. Works on other forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, parsley.js

I am trying to use parsley-rails validation on some forms in my rails app. Problem is that it works perfectly on some forms and doesn't submit on other forms.

I've tried adding required true to all form elements. I have also used different variations of "data-parsley-validate" => true, "data-parsley-validate" => "". Nothing seems to work. Here is the code to the form that works.

```
= simple_form_for(([@place, @place.reviews.build]), html: {"data-parsley-validate" => true}) do |f|
 %p= "Please rate your experience"
  .rating-form
  %hr
  = f.input :comment, input_html: {maxlength: 1000, rows: 10}, label: "Please describe your experience at the location", hint: "Enter a brief description of your experience", error: "You must provide a description for this review.", required: true
  %hr
  = f.submit "Review this place", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large"



:javascript
  $('.rating-form').raty({
    path: '/assets',
    scoreName: 'review[rating]'
  });
```

However, I'm unable to submit this form after validation:

```
= simple_form_for(@place, html: {class: "form-group", "data-parsley-validate" => true}) do |f|

 = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name, label: "Please enter the name of your place", hint: "eg. Papa Chris's Pizza.", required: true
    = f.label :Select_a_category
    %br
    = f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Please choose a category", required: true
    %br
    = f.input :short_description, label: "Please enter a short description of your place", hint: "eg. Papa Chris's Pizza.", required: true
    = f.input :description, as: :trix_editor, input_html: {maxlength: 1000, rows: 10}, label: "Please describe your place", hint: "Enter a brief description of your place", required: true
    = f.attachment_field :place_images_files, direct: true, multiple: true
    = f.simple_fields_for :locations do |location|
      = location.input :address, label: "Please enter the address of your place", hint: "eg. Lumumba Drive", required: true
      = location.input :city, label: "Please enter the city of your promotion", hint: "eg. Tema", required: true
    = f.input :phone, label: "Please enter your phone number", hint: "eg. 030 412 3123", :input_html => { :maxlength => 10, :"data-mask" => "999 999 9999" }, required: true
    = f.input :mobile_number,label: "Please enter your mobile number", hint: "eg. 020 111 2222", :input_html => { :maxlength => 10, :"data-mask" => "999 999 9999" }, required: true
    = f.input :website,label: "Please enter your website", hint: "eg. papajohns.com"
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery-ui
//= require ./jquery.raty.js
//= require jquery.timepicker.js
//= require jquery-mask-plugin
//= require jquery.slick
//= require parsley
//= require refile
//= require trix
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require leaflet
//= require dropzone
//= require underscore
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```

My application.css

```
 *= require leaflet
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require_tree
 *= require_self
 *= require trix
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require jquery.timepicker.css
 *= require dropzone/dropzone
 *= require parsley
 */
```

Nothing shows in the console and web inspector. The submit button just won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Trix is triggering parsley validation on a disabled input.  See [this Trix issue](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/248).  The solution is to add 
'data-parsley-excluded="[disabled]"
to your form, like this:

```
<form data-parsley-validate data-parsley-excluded="[disabled]">
  <trix-editor></trix-editor>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```